# ColdFusion click event?

Tags: events, coldfusion

I have two links on a page.

When the user clicks on one link, I'd like to set a ColdFusion variable, and when they click on another link, I'd like to set the variable to something else.

Is this possible to do? I'd like to avoid a JavaScript solution because the contents of the variable needs to be (semi) secure...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried adding a URL parameter to the link? (index.cfm?link=foo vs index.cfm?link=bar)

Then when the target page reloads, you can use a cfparam variable:

```
<cfparam name="var" default="">
```

An Adobe example follows:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7faf.html